# comparing "string" and "null" in linq to entity

Tags: oracle, linq, entity-framework-4

My code:

```
string name;
db.Entities.Where(m=>m.name==(name??m.name))
throw:Should be CHAR, but get NCLOB.
```

//----------------

```
  decimal? id;
  db.Entities.Where(m=>m.id==(id??m.id))
  The code is working.
```

my database is oracle.
What should I do to make the code working.?

Thanks.

Comment: And what is the type of `m.name` ?

Answer (score 4):

Beware that in Oracle an empty string is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Oracle + EF and type mappings. But this is not the way to make predicates optional anyway, because now the part `x ?? x.y` will always be part of the expression that is translated into SQL. This may hit query optimization and performance.

The way to do this is:

```
IQueryable<Entity> query = db.Entities;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
{
    query = query.Where(m => m.Name == name);
}
```